# Element not in array javascript & replace array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

These are checkboxes

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="114" id="category_id" >Mouse</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="89,809,watches"  name="selector[]" class="category" id="category_id" >Watches</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="809" id="category_id" >Men</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="89" id="category_id" >Women</label>
```

This is the function i write for take value from check box .

```
$('.category').click(function() {
    var val = [];
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        val[i] = jQuery(this).val();
    }); 
});
```

here if some one select men(809) or women(89) without clicking watch(89,809,watches) then i need to remove corresponding value from array val

*ie* some one select `men` then `val=array('809');` but it val must be null if some one select men without watch . if some one select mouse and men then val must be val=array('114');

i tried this code for checking but not worked

```
if((.inArray(val, 89))||(.inArray(val, 809)) && (!(.inArray(val, '89,809,watches')))){
    alert('watch not selected ');
}
```

and how to remove the value from array ?

Comment: It looks that you have lost some of your code. At least the .inArray doesn't make sense without anything before it

Comment: but please see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: Exactly! There's a DOLLAR before the .inArray :)

Comment: *and how to remove the value from array ?* So do you actually want to remove a value (array element) from an array or just get it's value to process?

Comment: He always (on every click) starts with an empty array, then he fills it. That should be OK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer is a working one. But I am not sure if the condition is correct or not.

```js
$('.category').click(function() {
    var val = [];
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
        selected = jQuery(this).val();  
        if( (selected == '89' || selected == '809') &&  !( $.inArray('89,809,watches', val) != -1 ) )
            return true;
        else
            val.push( selected );
    }).get(); 
    console.log(val);
    $('#arrayVal').text( 'Array String: "' + val.toString() + '"' )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="114" id="category_id" >Mouse</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="89,809,watches"  name="selector[]" class="category" id="category_id" >Watches</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="809" id="category_id" >Men</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="category" name="selector[]" value="89" id="category_id" >Women</label>

<div id="arrayVal"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it depends on the order of which each is looping over the checkboxes, which probably is the order of the appereance in the html. However it would be logical to accept the state of the checkboxes depending only on their state and not depending on their order on the page IMHO

Answer (score 0):

```
if(($.inArray(89, val)>-1)||($.inArray(809,val)>-1) && (($.inArray('89,809,watches', val)==-1))){
    alert('watch not selected ');
}
```

It's a pity that you know which manual page to read, but you don't read it...

1. you need to pass the value you search for in the 1st argument, and the array you search in in the 2nd argument
2. it returns the index or -1 if not found

Comment: Thank you . Sorry it's my mistake .